# Module pattern vs constructor in Javascript

Tags: javascript

What are the pros/cons of using module pattern versus a simple object constructor like this?:

```
function Car() {
  var _mileage = 123;
  this.bar = function() {
      console.log(_mileage);
  }
}
```

Both allow for private variables and methods, then why and when is module pattern needed or recommended?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's 2020 on the calendar - you can use `class` already.

Comment: That's not the module pattern. It's just a plain old ES5 constructor function.

Comment: arent private properties defined with `#` infront of it? like `#mileage = 123;`

Comment: @Ifaruki that's a proposed feature.

Comment: @t.niese ah okey

Comment: @zerkms I know, but I'm just curious

Comment: @VLAZ Yes, that wasn't an example of module pattern but an example of constructor function

Comment: The two are *hardly* equivalent, though. You have a lot less control with a normal constructor function. The smallest possible example is that you cannot share a "private" variable (defined in the inner scope) with methods attached on the prototype. You can attach methods directly to each instance but it's usually inefficient to do that.

Comment: I see. However there's no problem in defining methods as I did in my example, is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both create the module pattern and the one you show uses scopes to limit the access to variables and functions, and create a closure over those.

The module pattern ist primarily used to create one object:

```
var car = (function () {
    var _mileage = 123;

    function bar() {
      console.log(_mileage);
    }

    return {
        bar: bar
    };
}());
```

While the one you show allows creating multiple objects that are an instance of `Car`.

```
var car1 = new Car();
var car2 = new Car();

console.log(car1 instanceof Car); // true
console.log(car2 instanceof Car); // true
```

Comment: Ok so before ES6 how would you emulate a class (having multiples instances of Car)?

Comment: @mondrakerrider I don't understand what you mean. The code you showed in your question allows creating multiple instances of `Car`.

Comment: I mean, before ES6 classes, what was a valid approach to emulate classes with all the advantages they provide? a simple constructor like the one I showed is ok?

Comment: @mondrakerrider That's a new/different topic then you asked in your question, and there are many Q&A about that here on SO. [MDN: Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) `JavaScript classes, introduced in ECMAScript 2015, are primarily syntactical sugar over JavaScript's existing prototype-based inheritance. The class syntax does not introduce a new object-oriented inheritance model to JavaScript`

Comment: @t.niese "_primarily_"